# DH key with length 1024 bits but the client is configured to receive a key with length of at least 2048

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I have a TIBCO BW process that makes a web service call to another server via https. In our test environment the call works correctly however in our production environment we are getting the following exception.

The server key exchange message: DHE_RSA contains a weak DH key. The server sent a DH key with length 1024 bits but the client is configured to receive a key with length of at least 2048 bits at com.tibco.plugin.share.security.TIBCryptClientSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ...

Where in TIBCO BW is this limitation being specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8, this setting may solve the issue:

In your machine, edit the file: C:\tibco\bw\\lib\com\tibco\deployment\bwengine.xml

Include this property:

```
<property>
           <name>TIBCO SECURITY VENDOR</name>
           <option>java.property.TIBCO_SECURITY_VENDOR</option>
           <default>j2se</default>
           <description>TIBCO SECURITY VENDOR</description>
</property>
```

Save the file and generate a new EAR.

Answer (score 0):

java.property.TIBCO_SECURITY_VENDOR=j2se property in application tra file and restarting the application worked

Comment: post it in comments